# Escaping makefile variables (for internal makefile use)

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to "safely" expand a variable in a makefile, escaping all characters that makefile considers special?

As an example, assume that a variable is used as a target:

```
${external_chaos}:
    dd if=/dev/zero of=${external_chaos}
```

(drama in example intentional)

If `external_chaos` contains spaces, `;`, `#`, `:`, `,`, or other makefile-significant characters, then the whole rule gets messed up.

What I imagine as a solution is some Make built-in function that should do this, such as `${escape external_chaos}` (imaginary luxury).

`${value external_chaos}` doesn't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you won't succeed (without massive pain, if at all) in using targets with spaces in them.  Just give it up.  If you must support targets with spaces in them then choose a different build tool, not make.

The short answer is no, there's no built-in function.  You can write one yourself using `subst`; for example in targets you need to escape at least `%` and `:`:

```
TESCAPE = $(subst :,\:,$(subst %,\%,$1))
```

On the other hand, note that `;` and `,` are not special in targets so you don't need to escape them at all; in fact if you do you'll get incorrect results because the `\` will be left in the target name: backslash is only removed if it's quoting a special character.

`#` is special when you *define* the variable, but not when the variable is *expanded*: the parser has already finished looking for comments by then.  So you'll have to write:

```
external_chaos = foo\#bar,biz;baz:boz%bin
```

to get the `#` into the variable in the first place, but once it's there you don't need to escape it when the variable is used.

The next interesting thing is that you need to escape differently for targets and prerequisites.  So for example, in a target you must *not* escape `;`, but in a prerequisite you *must* escape `;`.  So you need different macros:

```
PESCAPE = $(subst :,\:,$(subst ;,\;,$1))

TESCAPE = $(subst :,\:,$(subst %,\%,$1))

all: $(call PESCAPE,${external_chaos})

$(call TESCAPE,${external_chaos}): ; echo '$@'
```

gives:

```
foo#bar,biz;baz:boz%bin
```

Comment: What about `%`? Or does that fall into the space-pain category?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to escape `%` as well.  I didn't try to think up all the possible special characters, just used the ones in the question.  Handling `%` is no big deal, same as colon.  The annoying thing is that different characters need to be escaped in different contexts: for example in a target context you do NOT want to escape `;`, but in a prerequisite context you MUST escape `;`.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Is there any reason why ESCAPE would not work for space characters? A quick test I just wrote seems to be fine: `ESCAPE = $(subst ${onespace},\${onespace},${1})`, where `onespace := ${nullstr} # space here` and `nullstr :=`, `v123 := one two three`, `${call ESCAPE,${v123}}:` gets called with `make 'one two three'` (terribly sorry for so much code in a comment).

Comment: Try using `$(@D)` or `$(@F)`.  Or any other make function on any of these.  Try to write a recipe that prints the prerequisites of your rule (using `$^`) preserving spaces in the name (for example printing one prerequisite per line, or using "ls" to list the files, etc.--passing them to a linker is the same thing).

Comment: I should say, you CAN make this work if (a) you are willing to escape spaces in all targets and prerequisites, (b) you are willing to never use any make automatic variables in your recipes that may expand to multiple words (so no `$^`, `$?`, `$+`, etc.), and (c) you are willing to never use any make functions on any variable that might contain space-separated words, including `$(@F)` (which is just shorthand for `$(notdir $@)`) etc.  Oh and you have to write all your own rules with proper quoting and not use any of make's built-in rules.  That's AT LEAST what you'll have to do.